# HTML code inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have to show in my webpage some html things and one of my goals is "Explain how to make tables". So I have a div like this

```
<div class="maind">
 contetn
</div>
```

The class `maind` has all the css properties that I need. By the way, I have to show the HTML code of the table inside the div. How could I do it?

[image]

As you can see here, on the left there is the result I have. On the right there's what I am trying to do. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to escape the HTML characters so that they are not rendered by the browser.

```
&lt;table border="1" &gt;
    &lt;tr%gt;
    etc...
    &lt;/tr&gt;
&lt;/table&gt;
```

`&lt;` will render as `<`, `&gt;` will render as `>`.

You can actually get away with only using `&lt;` while still using the `>` character at the end, e.g. `&lt;table>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **syntax highlighting library** if you also want your code to be colored. I can recommend you two libraries:

- [Highlight.js](http://highlightjs.org): is a Javascript library very easy to use. You almost only have to include this library in your HTML. [Here](http://highlightjs.org/usage/) you can see the basic usage.
- [Pygments](http://pygments.org): a Python library (used by [Github](https://github.com)). It is more popular but you have to compile the code before inserting it in your `HTML` code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply a style to an html element, you have to give it the style attribute first by doing this:

```
<table style="......">
   .......
</table>
```

Inside that style attribute you can give your height and width and any other property you might need.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/epbLk/)

So in this case if you want to create a table, this is the structure:

```
<table border="1" style="width:300px">
<tr>
  <td>Jill</td>
  <td>Smith</td>        
  <td>50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Eve</td>
  <td>Jackson</td>      
  <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, you have to give the style attribute first.

[Demo for table](http://jsfiddle.net/V3GC4/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this HTML encoder web app: http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/HTMLEncode/encode.aspx

Generate and put output code on div. :D